# C# Metro Unable to access object properties from List<Object>

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Trying to build a Windows 8 App using C# and XAML.

I've created a class:

```
class Tile
{
    public Tile(int ID, string Name, double Frequency, double Divider, int Value, int Turns, int StartLevel)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Frequency = Frequency;
        this.Divider = Divider;
        this.Value = Value;
        this.Turns = Turns;
        this.StartLevel = StartLevel;
    }

    private int ID { get; set; }
    private string Name { get; set; }
    private double Frequency { get; set; }
    private double Divider { get; set; }
    private int Value { get; set; }
    private int Turns { get; set; }
    private int StartLevel { get; set; }
}
```

I've added objects to a list:

```
List<Tile> tList = new List<Tile>();

tList.Add(new Tile(0, "Example1", 0.08, 1.00, 0, 7, 1));
tList.Add(new Tile(1, "Example2", 0.21, 1.25, 0, 0, 1));
```

When using standard C#, I'm able to access the properties of an object like such:

```
foreach (Tile t in tList)
{
    int test = t.ID;
}
```

**The Problem:**
In my foreach statement above, when I type "t." all that comes up in this list of available elements is:

Equals
GetHashCode
GetType
ToString

**I Expect:**
The following elements to appear:

ID
Name
Frequency
Divider
Value
Turns
StartLevel

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your properties in your Tile class are set to private. To be able to access the properties from outside the class you will need to declare them as public:

```
public class Tile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Frequency { get; set; }
    public double Divider { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Turns { get; set; }
    public int StartLevel { get; set; }
}
```

You can keep your same constructor, although that will end up being a mess to maintain as you add/subtract properties. Another way you can instantiate your list of Tile objects is like so:

```
List<Tile> tList = new List<Tile>
{
    new Tile
    {
       ID = 0,
       Name = "Example1"
    }
};
```

...for as many public properties as you need to set.